# supressing table of contents in pander package

Tags: pandoc, r-markdown, pander

This is a question about the R packager "pander"
I am using the live report generation feature of pander. I find this a useful, minimal way to get selected R results into a readable and sharable document.
Whenever it exports the report to an html file, it has a "Table of contents" link as a left panel.
It links to the pander website and this could be a distraction with reports.
Is there some pander option to not have this "Table of contents" panel?
Thank you,
jg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify your own `options` (e.g. a custom HTML template and CSS stylesheet) and even suppress the footer if you wish. Quick demo without the automatically added "Table of contents" panel:

```
x <- Pandoc$new()
x$add(head(iris))
x$format <- 'html'
x$export(footer = FALSE, options = '-s')
```